# Is `this` allowed inside a noexcept specification?

Tags: c++, this, language-lawyer, noexcept

I have some code which requires me to use `*this`, but I want it to be noexcept friendly:

```
struct foo;

// Would actually be something with conditional noexcept
void do_something(foo&);

struct foo {
    void fn()
        noexcept(noexcept(::do_something(*this)))
    {
        ::do_something(*this);
    }
};
```

However, [gcc rejects this](https://godbolt.org/z/3rK4Yz):

```
<source>:7:43: error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
         noexcept(noexcept(::do_something(*this)))
```

If I just access a member, gcc is fine:

```
void do_something(int);

struct bar {
    int x;

    void fn()
        noexcept(noexcept(::do_something(x)))
    {
        ::do_something(x);
    }
};
```

However, if I access the member through the `this` pointer, [gcc complains again](https://godbolt.org/z/HBm5t9):

```
struct baz {
    int x;

    void fn()
        noexcept(noexcept(::do_something(this->x)))
    {
        ::do_something(this->x);
    }
};
```

Diagnostic:

```
<source>:7:42: error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
         noexcept(noexcept(::do_something(this->x)))
```

Every other compiler I tried [accepts using `this` inside the noexcept specification](https://godbolt.org/z/8xnUVI), but I don't actually know if it's gcc that has the bug or all the other compilers.

Can the keyword `this` be used inside a noexcept specification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. [[expr.prim.this]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#2) says:

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X`, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`” between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, [...].

The *cv-qualifier-seq* refers to the cv qualifiers of the member function, which [appear before the noexcept specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#nt:parameters-and-qualifiers):

> ```
> parameters-and-qualifiers:
>     ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq[opt] ref-qualifier[opt] 
>       noexcept-specifier[opt] attribute-specifier-seq[opt]
> ```

So, `this` is a valid expression to use in the *noexcept-specifier*. This was a DR ([cwg1207](https://wg21.link/cwg1207)), which gcc doesn't implement. The [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52869).

Comment: Nice find on the bug report. I searched in the gcc bugzilla, but didn't find this.

Comment: @Justin I searched for "this noexcept" :)